# Is there a way to automatically fit the chart control height to histogram display in the chart size?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, histogram

I'm displaying histogram of a selected image in a chart control.
the problem is with images like the most color in it is black then some peak's in the chart are too high and getting "out" from inside the chart control.

is there any way to automatically fit the control to the histogram size or to fit the histogram chart to the control ?

I marked with red circles the two places where the histogram is too high:

[image: histogram]

this is my code:

```
using OpenCvSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Image_Manipulator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Mat image;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void LoadAndDisplayImage(string imagePath)
        {
            image = Cv2.ImRead(imagePath); // Assign the loaded image to the class-level variable
            Bitmap bitmap = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(image);
            pictureBoxImage.Image = bitmap;
        }

        private void CalculateAndDisplayHistogram(Mat image)
        {
            Mat grayImage = new Mat();
            Cv2.CvtColor(image, grayImage, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);

            Mat hist = new Mat();
            int[] channels = { 0 };
            int[] histSize = { 256 };
            Rangef[] ranges = { new Rangef(0, 256) };
            Cv2.CalcHist(new[] { grayImage }, channels, null, hist, 1, histSize, ranges);

            // Clear previous data in the chart
            chartHistogram.Series.Clear();
            var series = chartHistogram.Series.Add("Histogram");
            series.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;

            for (int i = 0; i < hist.Rows; i++)
            {
                series.Points.AddXY(i, hist.At<float>(i));
            }
        }

        private void buttonLoadImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                openFileDialog.Filter = "Image Files|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif"; // Add more image formats as needed

                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string selectedImagePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

                    // Load and display the selected image
                    LoadAndDisplayImage(selectedImagePath);

                    // Calculate and display the histogram for the selected image
                    CalculateAndDisplayHistogram(image);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```